# Transaction (Process ID) was deadlocked errors

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am having an issue with my code and the numerous SQL calls that it makes with deadlocks. I pasted the code into PasteBin here: https://pastebin.com/p1YDkKsB. Can someone help me out here? It happens most often in the CheckClanActivity task here:

```
using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(string.Format("select * from ClanMembers where MembershipId={0} and IsActive = 1", entry.Player.DestinyUserInfo.MembershipId), conn))
```

, but it also happens all over the place.

Edit:
Okay, the involved SQL statements are as follows:

```
if not exists(select * from ClanMembers where MembershipId={0}) begin insert into ClanMembers(ID, MembershipId, BattleNetId, ClanId, DateLastPlayed, IsActive, LastUpdated) select ISNULL(MAX(ID) + 1, 0),{0},'{1}',{2},'{3}', 1, GETDATE() from ClanMembers end else begin update ClanMembers set DateLastPlayed='{3}', LastUpdated=GETDATE() where MembershipId={0} end

if not exists(select * from ClanMemberCharacters where CharacterId={1}) begin insert into ClanMemberCharacters(ID,MembershipId,CharacterId) select ISNULL(MAX(ID)+1,0),{0},{1} from ClanMemberCharacters end

select c.* from ClanMemberCharacters c join ClanMembers m on m.MembershipId = c.MembershipId where m.IsActive = 1 ORDER BY m.MembershipId desc

select * from ActivityHistory where InstanceId = {0}

if not exists(select * from ActivityHistory where InstanceId = {0}) begin insert into ActivityHistory(InstanceId,MembershipId,CharacterId,GameMode,ActivityDate,ReferenceId,DirectorActivityHash,IsPrivate,ClanActivity,ClanActivityCount) values( {0},{1},{2},'{3}','{4}',{5},{6},{7},{8},{9} ) END

select * from ClanMembers where IsActive = 1

Select * from ClanMembers where IsActive = 0

update ClanMembers set IsActive = 1 where MembershipId = {0}

select * from ClanMembers where MembershipId={0} and IsActive = 1
```

Comment: Yeah. Deadlock graphs? ALL involved statements, execution plans, table structures please.

Comment: I updated the question with all the SQL statements being used, but I dont have any deadlock graphs to share as the host I'm using doesn't allow this access. As far as the execution plans are concerned, the order the statements are in is the order in which they execute.

Comment: Well, then grab a book and start a tace and get the graphs beacuse they tell you what is deadlocking. SImple as that. Btw., awfull code to use ISNULL to get a new ID instead of using the sql server integrated identity columns, or sequences. Back to documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is the nesting of `SqlConnection`s with the same connection string one within the other. Suggestions:

1. Move the connection `using` as close to the scope of the command as possible. For example, avoid calls to your other methods from within it.
2. Avoid the `if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed) { conn.Open(); }` and simply move the `conn.Open();` to be the first thing inside the using of the `SqlConnection`.
3. Remove the `conn.Close()` which will be done automatically when leaving the `using` block.
4. `SqlDataAdapter` is also disposable so should be in a `using` block.
5. The way you catch and swallow exceptions means the caller has no idea that something has gone wrong. Consider rethrowing the exception with `throw;` or not catching the exception here, and catching it higher up the call stack.
6. The way you are logging the errors will not help you diagnose the problem. Consider logging `ex.ToString()` rather than just `ex.Message`.
7. Separate your concerns. You are cramming everything together. Refactor your code so that the data layer is separated from the business logic.
8. Avoid doing `string.Format` to construct your queries, because by doing so they are vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Thanks for this response. I'm pretty sure these suggestions have solved my issue, but there's a lot of data this app goes through, so I'll find out in a few hours.